# How to check if a string is a valid HHMMSS value in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code does not seem to do the trick when I pass the following to it:

"023000" and "HHMMSS"

I get back "000000" no matter what.

```
Function formatTime(tStr As String, tFormat As String) As String
    If tStr <> "" Then
        formatTime = format(tStr, tFormat)
    Else
        formatTime = "NAT" 'Not A Time
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: `023000` is not a valid string you can convert into a time value, look at [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) and [TimeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want the Time equivalent of the IsDate function. However, as there's no native *IsTime* function, you can make one yourself:

```
Sub Is_It_A_Time()
    Debug.Print IsTime("12:34:56") ' Returns True
    Debug.Print IsTime("12:34:60") ' Returns False
    Debug.Print IsTime("13:34:00") ' Returns True
    Debug.Print IsTime("25:01:02") ' Returns False
End Sub

Function IsTime(Expression As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsDate(Expression) Then
        IsTime = (Int(CSng(CDate(Expression))) = 0)
    End If
End Function
```